# Angular is possible to use ngSwitch on numeric range?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to use ngSwitch based on numeric value range.

I would like to show three different text based on ngSwitch change. However I cannot get this work when I try to set a value range in ng-switch-when. Is this possible or should I use ngIf instead of ngSwitch?

http://jsbin.com/eWIQoJE/1/edit

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not possible.

The [ngSwitch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) directive checks if the value in `ngSwitchWhen` is **equal** to the one in `ngSwitch`. Instead, you can use `ngShow` or `ngIf` as you have proposed:

```
 <div ng-if="test === 0">Is zero</div>
 <div ng-if="test > 10">Is greater than 10</div>
 <div ng-if="!(test === 0 || test > 10)">Default</div>
```

<kbd>[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ELaDuza/2/edit)</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

It is possible, but you need to declare a helper function in your scope

In your controller:

```
$scope.switchHelper = function(value) {
  if (value === 0)
    return 0;
  if (value > 10)
    return 1;
  if (!(value === 0 || test))
    return 3;
};
```

An in HTML:

```
<div ng-switch="switchHelper(test)">
     <div ng-switch-when="0">Is zero</div>
     <div ng-switch-when="1">Is greater than 10</div>
     <div ng-switch-when="3">Default</div>
</div>
```

As [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ELaDuza/3/).

Comment: Unreadable as it. We can add constants to improve the solution, but that will be very heavy. Not a good proposal, IMHO.

Comment: I think this is a viable options in some scenarios (when checks are more complex), but you're right on the readability. If some one really goes this way it might be better to use strings or something else as return values.

Comment: @Blackhole IMO its ok if you use meaningful strings instead of 0,1,3 ...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ternary operator with `ng-init` directive. Like this:

```
<div ng-init="value = (test == 0 ? 0 : (test > 10 ? 1 : null))" ng-switch="value">
    <div ng-switch-when="0">Is zero</div>
    <div ng-switch-when="1">Is greater than 10</div>
    <div ng-switch-default>Default</div>
</div>
```

Seem complex, but works as expected without view logic in controller.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript

```js
app.controller('numberCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.someNum = 0;
    $scope.someVal = 0;

    $scope.updateVal = function () {
        if (($scope.someNum >= 1) && ($scope.someNum <= 5)) {
            $scope.someVal = 1;
        } else {
            $scope.someVal = 0;
        }
    }
});
```

In HTML

```js
<div ng-controller="numberCtrl">
            <label>Enter a value from 1 to 5</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="someNum" ng-change="updateVal()" />
            <div ng-switch="someVal">
                <p ng-switch-when="1">You entered {{someNum}}</p>
                <p ng-switch-when="0">Invalid input</p>
            </div>        
        </div>
```